# How to disable native "datalist" / autocomplete in Google Chrome?

Tags: forms, google-chrome, input, autocomplete

I am experiencing an issue with Google Chrome today. I am writing a JS plugin called Awesomplete, it is a autocomplete plugin. The plugin works wonderfully in every browser except for Google Chrome. The plugin works, except Google Chrome is ignoring my autocomplete="off" pleas and throwing in its own suggestions which, of course, appear over Awesomplete's generated content.

Whenever I type into my input, Google Chrome automatically creates a menu below the input, exactly as if there was a datalist attached to the input (which there isn't). This false "datalist" appears over the Awesomplete suggestions making the plugin useless. I have searched and searched without success. I have tried both autocomplete="false" and autocomplete="off" on the form, and on the input. I also have aria-autocomplete="off" on there even though I'm not sure what that does. I have even tried a suggestion from others to put to "fake" inputs at the beginning of the field, so that Google Chrome's autocomplete feature will attack them instead of the real input. Yeah, no go.

Most of my users are using Google Chrome, so this is a problem for me. Is there anything I can do? Or I'm I left helplessly powerless to the browser, who for some reason the devs decided to take form matters into their own hands.

```
<input required type="search" data-list="<?php echo $list; ?>" class="awesomplete" name="gameSearch" size="50" placeholder="Search for game titles here!" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list">
```

$list is a generated list of game titles courtesy of some php before the input.

Comment: UPDATE!!! I have narrowed the problem down to Google Chrome's habit of remembering what users typed into a specific field. The "suggestions" are past searches. So I would want to disable that specifically...if possible. Changing the name of the input fixed the problem, but as soon as I performed one search the problem was back.  Since it remembers the first search.......

Comment: Is this a problem with Chrome itself or does the JS library remove the autocomplete attribute from the input?

Comment: This is chrome. It's noted in several different places that Chrome ignores the autocomplete attribute now. This specifically is chrome remembering search inputs, and suggesting them upon another search. A normally useful feature, but not in my case. I am working on a work around, it seems that having just an input and using JS to handle the input would work. since it's not a "form" chrome will not try to suggest things. Still testing though.

Comment: OK. If you do manage to solve the problem, you can post that as an answer to your question here. Maybe other people will be interested in the solution too.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty much sure chrome does it by matching the 'id'/'name'. At this point of time, I guess there is no solution other than removing them off your datalist.